# Does FFmpeg support Openmax IL HW decoder?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoder, decoder, openmax

Dears:

Does FFmpeg support Openmax IL HW ***decoder***?

I have found & could use FFmpeg Openmax IL HW encoder which named omx.c.

However, I did not find  Openmax IL HW decoder implementation for FFmpeg?

Does there anyone know why?

Or someone has the experience to implement Openmax IL HW decoder for FFmpeg.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Talking of an OpenMAX IL encoder: Does this work for the Xilinx MPSoC FPGAs that support OMX?